# Is there a way to change the name of specific accounts in the User folder of Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, filesystems, user-accounts

During the setting up of a new computer, I accidentally switched the account names for my customary admin account and regular user account. Is there a way for me to switch the folder names under the User folder? It's mostly for my peace of mind when installing and navigating my filesystem.

The only idea I've had so far is to change the names manually; when I tried this, Windows wouldn't recognize my files as belonging to the account on login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, but that will break already installed applications that store full path to the user profile directory, such as [Google Drive and iCloud](http://hron.me/blog/2013/04/rename-windows-8-profile-dir/).

Here is [Microsoft's guide for Windows 7](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2454362):

1. Log in by using another administrative account.

Note You may need create a new administrative account at first.

2. Go to the `C:\users\` folder and rename the sub folder with the original user name to the new user name.
3. Go to registry and modify the registry value `ProfileImagePath` to the new path name.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\<User SID>\`

**WARNING**: If you use Registry Editor incorrectly, you may cause serious problems that may require you to reinstall your operating system. Microsoft cannot guarantee that you can solve problems that result from using Registry Editor incorrectly. Use Registry Editor at your own risk.

4. Log out and log in again by using the user whose name is changed, and the user should use the previous profile with new path name.

More [detailed guide is also available on sevenforums](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/147545-user-profile-folder-change-user-account-folder-name.html), which tries to mitigate common issues.

Answer (score 1):

User account *names* can be changed, but the user profile folders cannot be changed. The only solution is to delete both accounts and profiles and start over.